# Using pull-right inside element aligns the text with the center. How do I align it with the baseline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I've looked around SO, and I've found the inverse of this question mostly everywhere. That makes me feel this is either a rarer occurrence, or something trivial that I just can't figure out.

https://jsfiddle.net/je5dpqrL/

The above jsFiddle shows that I have an `<h2>` element within which I've put an anchor tag with the `pull-right` class of Bootstrap. Since I want the anchor to display in a smaller font, I'm using `font-weight` and `font-size`. Now, since it's floating, the text is centered.

Is there any way to align the text so that the baseline of the Title and the `<a>` element is the same?

Comment: In your case if your "stuff" is going to be text on a single line I would use `.cl {line-height: 54px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The following code seems to work:

```
<h2>Text<a class="pull-right"><span class="text-right" style="display:inline-block">Test</span></a></h2>
```

Turns out that adding an `.inside-block` to an element inside the `.pull-right` class seems to fix it. No need to play around with `line-height`s

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/je5dpqrL/10/

EDIT: Thanks to Diamond for this suggestion of adding an element inside the `<a>` tag, although the CSS is completely different from the one suggested by him.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the vertical position of the `<a>` with line-height (and use for example `em` to make it relative size):

```
.cl {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:4em
}
```

Comment: line-height: 4em will make the link height bigger than h2

Comment: Why, specifically did you use 4em? And how do I ensure that the line-height is correctly calculated to make the baselines match?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need https://jsfiddle.net/p05bu4c2. Create a span inside the link

```css
.cl {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 40%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.cl span {
 line-height: 1;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

h2 {
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title <a class='pull-right cl'><span>Stuff</span></a></h2>
```

Comment: This still doesn't have the same baseline. It seems lower. Is there something wrong I'm doing?  - https://jsfiddle.net/je5dpqrL/9/

Comment: set ".cl span" line-height to 20px or 25px which is half of "h2" line-height